# What kind of sensor could detect insects moving in the dark?

Tags: sensors

I live in a condo in a large urban area, which means that cockroaches are inevitable. I thought of an a DiY project I could embark on to help control these pests in my home.

Basically I would have a box with a piston attached to a crusher, with bait at the back of the box, see the diagram below.

```
-----------------------------
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|  bait    -----------------
-----------------------------
```

The box would be designed in such a way that the roaches would have to travel underneath the crusher to reach the bait. The crusher would be activated once any roach crossed the middle of the crusher.

My question is, what kind of device could be used to detect the insects in the dark?

Comment: a camera ......

Comment: I explicitly said it would be dark, so a camera would probably not have enough light to detect the cockroaches

Comment: You can use a camera [without infrared filter](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/pi-noir-camera-v2/), and an infrared light. Also, I think it might be a lower-cost option to make a passive system (i.e. without actuators and sensors) e.g. similar to a [fly trap](https://www.thespruce.com/how-to-make-a-fly-trap-1389066)?

Comment: Infrared sounds like a great idea. Actually I recall hearing that some insects may even be attracted to infrared light. I'd rather have a crusher than the passive system since it would ensure a 0 probability of escape for any insect reaching the bait/food. Although I realized that the noise of the piston activating in the middle of the night could be problematic

Comment: do roaches enter an area that contains dead roaches?

Comment: They do. Will they avoid the area if they can detect dead roaches?